# Form validation issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I have created a method in javascript for validate all input elements inside a form

this was my form

```
<form name="frmRegister" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<ul>
<li>
  <input  type="text"   validate="true" regex="" displayname="card number 1" name="inpt1"  >
</li>
<li>
<input  type="text"   validate="true" regex="" displayname="card number 2" name="inpt5"  >
</li>
<li>
 <input  type="text"   validate="true" regex="" displayname="card number 3" name="inpt2"  >
</li>
<li>
 <input  type="text"   validate="true" regex="" displayname="card number 4" name="inpt3"  >
</li>
<li>
<input  type="text"   validate="true" regex="" displayname="card number 5" name="inpt4"  >
</li>
 </ul>
 <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="SEND"  />
 </form>
```

this was my method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(form_name)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < form_name.elements.length; i++) 
  {
    var elem = form_name.elements[i];
    var displayname = elem.getAttribute("displayname")
    var element_names="";
     if (elem.getAttribute("validate") == "true")
 {
    if(elem.value=="")
    {
      alert(displayname+" connot be null.");
      elem.focus();
      return false;

    }
    }

  }

  return true;

}
</script>
```

The problem is it not working in IE8 ,Its showing the alert messages but the form is still submitting so I am getting null values in my database.

Comment: Posted an updated answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form name="frmRegister" action="" method="post" onsubmit="event.returnValue = validate(this);">
```

Also, you are missing `;` in your code.

```
var elem = form_name.elements[i];
var displayname = elem.getAttribute("displayname")   //Here you miss ;
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

EDIT (checked in **Firefox**, **Opera**, **IE** and **Chrome**):

```
<form name="frmRegister" action="" method="post" onsubmit=" if (event.preventDefault) return validate(this) ; else  event.returnValue = validate(this) ; ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing below code of section.

```
if(elem.value=="" || elem.value == null)
{
  alert(displayname+" connot be null.");
  elem.focus();
  return false;

}
```